# How to dynamically add and remove mapped array to another array when clicked and remove from arr when clicked again in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a project where I mapped through a lisf of numbers from 1 to 90 and returned a button for each number, so when I click a particular button the color changes and when I click again the color goes away. So here is my problem I need to add the number in that button to a list when the button is clicked and and the color changes then remove it from the list when the button is clicked again and the color changes back to normal. This the codebase of what I did to add colors to the button when clicked and remove color when clicked again.

```
    import React from 'react';
    import './style.css'; 
    export default function App() {
      const [activeNums, setActiveNums] = React.useState({});
        let nums = []
        for (let i = 1; i < 91; i++) {
            nums.push(i)
        }
      const onToggle = (num) => {
        setActiveNums((state) => {
          return {
            ...state,
            [num]: !state[num],
          };
        });
      };
      return (
        <div>
          {nums.map(i => {
              return <button key={i} name={!activeNums[i] && 'ready'} onClick={(e) => 
              handleClass(i, e)} className={`${activeNums[i] ? 'game_clicked' : ''} 
              game_btn `}>{i}</button>
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: You haven't added what is happening right now with your code. We get what you want, but please add whi is happening now

Comment: Right now I can toggle the color on and off the numbers when clicked but not yet able to add each of those numbers to an array and remove them when clicked again.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

So as I understand you want to have buttons, which you click/unclick and adding button number to some object. Can be done like this:

```js
// import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [activeNums, setActiveNums] = React.useState({});

  const buttonHandler = ({ target: { name } }) => {    
    setActiveNums({ ...activeNums, [name]: !activeNums[name] });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {[...Array(10)].map((_, idx) => {
        const number = idx + 1;
        return (
          <button key={number} name={number} onClick={buttonHandler}>
            My number is: {number} <br />I am{" "}
            {activeNums["" + number] ? "" : "not"} ready.
          </button>
        );
      })}
      <div>{JSON.stringify(activeNums)}</div>
    </div>
  );
};

// export default App;

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/* I think this is what you were going for, hope this helps - */

    import React from "react";
    import "./styles.css";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [activeNums, setActiveNums] = React.useState([]);
      let nums = [];
      for (let i = 1; i < 91; i++) {
        nums.push(i);
      }
    
      const onToggle = (num) => {
        setActiveNums((prevState) => {
          if (prevState.includes(num)) {
            return [...prevState.filter((n) => n !== num)];
          } else {
            return [...prevState, num];
          }
        });
      };
    
      return (
        <div>
          {nums.map((num) => {
            return (
              <button
                key={num}
                onClick={(e) => onToggle(num)}
                className={activeNums.includes(num) ? "game_clicked" : ""}
              >
                {num}
              </button>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      );
    }
```